# Java - Using recursion to fill ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

What I am trying to do:

1. take all `User` from `user.getFriends()` and add it to `temp`
2. then from `user.getFriends()`, check those `User` objects and their `user.getFriends()` and add those to `temp`
3. `temp` cannot contain duplicates
4. lastly.. it must be done through recursion

Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<User> getRecommendations(User user, ArrayList<User> temp, int n)
{
    if (n<user.getFriends().size()){
        if (!temp.contains(user.getFriends().get(n))){
            temp.add(user.getFriends().get(n));
        }
        getRecommendations(user, temp, ++n);
    } return temp;
}
```

The gist of my problem is that I need to pass in a `User` object, add that objects friends (using `getFriends()`), and then get those object's friends (using the same method) all into a single `ArrayList<User>` using recursion...

From this method, I've been able to `getFriends()` of the initial `User` object being passed in. The recursion works fine in this case, but I cannot seem to figure out how I should design this code to get friends' of friends `User` objects.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah thanks. i'll remember that

Comment: That's just a plain graph-traversal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want every user just once, so a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is the better choice.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

What is done here is:

1. Add every friend of the current user to the own set.
2. Then for each friend, call the same method, and add the whole set returned from this.

You can sit down and draw a calling tree if this hard to understand. This often lights things up.

---

```
public Set<FacebookUser> getRecommendations(FacebookUser user, ArrayList<FacebookUser> alreadyVisited)
{
  Set<FacebookUser> friends = new HashSet<FacebookUser>();
  alreadyVisited.add(user);
  if (user.getFriends().size() > 0) {
      friends.addAll(user.getFriends());
      for(FacebookUser fbu : user.getFriends())
        if(!alreadyVisited.contains(fbu))
          friends.addAll(getRecommendations(fbu, alreadyVisited);
  }
  return friends;
}
```

---

If you really have to use an ArrayList, you can use something like the following, see the changes on the recursive getRecommendations call.

This now:

1. Adds all friends of the current user to the list.
2. Calls recursivly all friends of the current user, but adding only those which are not already in the list.

If you are new to Java, you may wonder what this `... .stream(). ...` is. For this you may have a look at Oracle's [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)-documentation.

```
public ArrayList<FacebookUser> getRecommendations(FacebookUser user, ArrayList<FacebookUser> alreadyVisited)
{
  ArrayList<FacebookUser> friends = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();
  alreadyVisited.add(user);
  if (user.getFriends().size() > 0) {
    friends.addAll(user.getFriends());
    for(FacebookUser fbu : user.getFriends())
      if(!alreadyVisited.contains(fbu))
        getRecommendations(fbu, alreadyVisited).stream().filter(x -> !friends.contains(x)).forEach(x -> friends.add(x));
  }
  return friends;
}
```

Comment: yeah now I've read that `Set` is the ideal collection use.. unfortunately this is for a class, so I'm forced to work with an ArrayList, but this should still work

Comment: You need to keep track of a boolean to mark as visited for each user, before you add it to set. Because you will end up in infinite loop with this code. Will keep on inserting parent from each child node. This is pretty much how traversing happens in graph nodes.

Comment: Then tell your teacher he should teach you right ;) But yeah, with slight modifications this should also be no problem.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand: You are right, totally have overseen this, will look into this.

Comment: I've updated the answer with both, fixes and a version that uses ArrayList.